# Way to override the doc_count based aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

```
{
 "date": "2015-06-25T17:20:20",
 "ip": "192.138.63.233",
 "ec": "106023",
 "sip": "160.141.161.137",
 "sport": "57735",
 "dip": "128.44.113.244",
 "dport": "389",
 "proto": "udp",
"bytesin": 125,
"bytesout": 250
 }
 {
 "date": "2015-06-25T17:20:20",
 "ip": "192.138.63.233",
 "ec": "106023",
 "sip": "160.141.162.162",
 "sport": "53576",
 "siface": "inside",
 "dip": "160.141.147.78",
 "dport": "389",
 "proto": "udp",
"bytesin": 225,
"bytesout": 550
}
```

I am a bit new to Elastic Search, We would like to run few aggregations on the above indexed documents.

Our intention is to get the top 10 "dip" fields which are having maximum sum of "bytesin" data.
My query in sql will be like "select dip, sum(bytesin) data from table group by dip order by sum(bytesin) desc".

```
currently I am running below GET request in Elastic Search but it is not providing what exactly the above sql query gives.

"aggs": {
 "top-sip": {
 "terms": {
 "field": "dip",
 "size": 10,
 "order": {
 "totalbytes": "desc"
 }
 },
 "aggs": {
 "totalbytes": {
 "sum": {
 "field" : "bytesin"
 }
 }
 }
 }
 }
```

The above aggregation retrieves the top 10 "dips" with respect to doc_count and then it aggregates the "bytesin" field for those top "dips".

But what I expect(sql query) is, group the "dips" and aggregates the "bytesin" field for the grouped dip's. Finally it retreive the top 10 dips with respect to sum(bytesin). This is a way to override the default aggregation on ‘doc_count’ of a field. For my use-case, identifying the top dips which are involved in consuming highest bandwidth (here bytesin field).

Can any one suggest me how to execute the aggregation to get the expected result.

Comment: Your query does exactly that. What is wrong with it? I don't understand. Can you give an example of failed result?

Comment: Hi Stefan,

Thank you for your quick reply. To explain it more clearly, Let us say I have the below dips with those many doc_count and sum(bytesin)
in elastic search index.



dip                   doc_count    sum(bytesin)
========      =========    ============
10.0.15.1        2000          100
10.0.15.2        1500          200
10.0.15.3        1000          300
10.0.15.4         800          400
10.0.15.5         700          500
10.0.15.6         200          600

Comment: when I execute the above mentioned aggregated query with size as 5, it only extracts the first 5 dips i.e. from 10.0.15.1 to 10.0.15.5 and then sorts the record with
respect to sum(bytesin).

But my expectation is to extract the top 5 records with respect to sum(bytesin) i.e. it has to extract the below records.  All I am trying to say is,  Elastic Search is extracting
top 5 dips with respect to doc_count(i.e. from 10.0.15.1 to 10.0.15.5) then it is aggregating the bytesin field for those dips.

Comment: dip              doc_count    sum(bytesin)
======      =========    ============
10.0.15.6        200           600
10.0.15.5        700           500
10.0.15.4        800           400
10.0.15.3        1000          300
10.0.15.2        1500          200

Comment: the only solution I can think of is change size of you aggs to 0, which well tell ES to aggs on all result set. Then once you get the result, just grab the first 10 dip in the return buckets.

Comment: @Raju This is what I tried: https://gist.github.com/astefan/3ff6819bd99ad4276ce6. And I still don't see a problem. It's giving back the results you showed: 10.0.5.6 to 10.0.5.2 in this order. Take a look, give my code a try and tell me what is wrong with it.

Comment: Hi Ryan, 
Thank you for your quick response. I think it would be difficult if we want to perform aggregation on 500 million documents and expecting all aggregated records.

Comment: He Stefan,
Thank You very much for your time on this. what You explained is correct. I misunderstood the concept.  It actually does the aggregation first then it does the ordering after the ordering only it fetches top 5 records.